# If I have a nested list for translating words how do I print the translation of a users input word?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a nested list as follows:

```
lst == [ ('cat', 'gatto'), ('one', 'uno'), ('two', 'due'), ('three', 'tre'), ('four', 'quattro') ]
```

And a user inputs the second element of any of these sublists how do I return the first element?

So if the user inputs 'gatto', the returned value is 'cat'

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer will be as the following but I suggest you learn about `dictionary` in python also which I mentioned in the second answer.

```
//First answer 
lst =[ ('cat', 'gatto'), ('one', 'uno'), ('two', 'due'), ('three', 'tre'), ('four', 'quattro') ]
inp = 'gatto'
for i in last:
    if inp == i[1]: 
        print(i[0])
```

You can use the python dictionary to store the elements which may be very useful in your case. Dictionary in python is very handy for such an application. Dictionary holds `key:value` pair. Key-value is provided in the dictionary to make it more optimized.

```
//Second way
dict = {'gatto' : 'cat', 'uno':'one', 'due':'two', 'tre': 'three', 'quattro':'four'}
print('gatto',dict['gatto']) 

return cat 
(as you wanted)
```

Also, note that you have given two `equals to` while defining your list. Only one is required.
Hope this helps you.